# Increment count in Pandas dataframe when values change and when time exceeds condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, window

Each time the value of Person changes, reset count to 0. Increment count each time the time is more than 2 from the initial increment.

```
Person Time DesiredResult
B      0    0
B      2    0
B      2    0
B      4    1
A      0    0
S      0    0
S      1    0
S      2    0
S      4    1
S      8    2
```

code to generate the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Alvin','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve']
                     ,'Time': [0,2,2,4,0,0,1,2,4,8]
                     ,'DesiredResult': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,2]})
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45egh.png) attached at the link below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45egh.png]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have not *DesiredResult* column.

To create it, define the following function:

```
def fn(grp):
    t0 = grp.iloc[0].Time
    return (grp.Time > t0 + 2).cumsum()
```

Then run:

```
df['DesiredResult'] = df.groupby('Person').apply(fn).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Alvin','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve']
                     ,'Time': [0,2,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,5,8,9]
                     ,'DesiredResult': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2]})

def fn(grp):
    t0 = grp.iloc[0].Time
    return (grp.Time > t0 + 2).cumsum()

df['DesiredResult2'] = df.groupby('Person').apply(fn).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df`

In this case each record for an individual person will increment once the 2 second window has been exceeded. This *almost*
 works, thanks for your response